# How to use all captured dynamic values in next request

Tags: performance, jmeter, beanshell, dynamic-variables

I have 2 requests Claims and update claims, for a user if I get 5 claims I need to run all the claims in the next request submitting all the claim values.

Claims=234,456,789,876,987
The above values are captured using regular expression extractor.
I need to run next request no of times we have claims for a user, So I'm using loop controller with match NR number [loop counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XR6Q.png).
Under loop counter I have a next request where I need to process all claims [Next request where claims are passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd1X3.png). I'm using counter to increment the captured value number and pass all claims [Counter used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFpY4.png).

But this method is not working to pass all the claims when I use counter.

I have tried [Counter to use all the claims](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c1Xa.png)  but it was not working.

When used this [Hardcoded number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPd3Q.png) it was working and same claim is processing loop number of times.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following [JMeter Variables defined](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) (you can see all created variables along with their respective values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter))

```
Claims_1=234
Claims_2=456
...
Claims_MatchNr=xxx
```

and would like:

- 1st request to use `234`
- 2nd request to use `456`
- etc

The correct syntax to refer the "next" variable under the loop would be `${__V(Claims_${count},)}`

Check out [__V() function documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) for more information

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T, it worked as expected. :)